# How can I filter Ember.Select content, instead of using {{each}} {{if}} handlebars filtering?

Tags: ember.js

Using the select method with handlebars each and if helpers I can successfully display an array where only those with active = true.

```
<select>
    {{#each content.users}}
        {{#if active}}
            <option value="">{{firstName}}</option>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

vs

```
{{view Ember.Select class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' style='max-width: 200px' 
    content=content.users 
    optionValuePath='content.id' 
    optionLabelPath='content.firstName'
    selectionBinding='someSelectionBinding'}}
```

The downside to the select way is I can't bind an action to the option value, and I lose out on some of the useful Ember Selection binding and label functionality/observers. Where the downside to the Ember.Select way is I can't set my content to only those users who have the active flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a recent version of Ember. In your controller, assuming an `Ember.ArrayController` with `content.users` defined as you seem to have it, you'll want to create a new attribute, like `activeUsers`:

```
App.ThisController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    // Other stuff
    activeUsers = Em.computed.filterBy('users', 'active', true)
})
```

This should give you an array of users where the `active` attribute is `true`, so you can set the content of your `Ember.Select` view to `content.activeUsers`.

Comment: Awesome. My content.users is actually a nested array inside a bigger object passed through my model. Adding activeUsers: Em.computed.filterBy('content.users', 'active', true), to my controller for that view worked perfectly. Thanks dude.